# my code skips a function

Tags: c#, webforms

i am making a form to create a item for my db but my code don't do a function

### the code

```
public partial class Create : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        Leraren leraar;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                if (Request.Form["edit"] != null)
                {
                    create();
                }
        }
        private void create()
        {
            string naam = Request.Form["txt_naam"];
            string voornaam = Request.Form["txt_voornaam"];
            string email = Request.Form["txt_email"];
            string foto = Request.Form["txt_foto"];

            try
            {
                leraar = new Leraren();
                leraar.CreateTeacher(naam, voornaam, email, foto);

                Response.Redirect("../Wie.aspx");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write("U hebt wat lege velden");
            }


        }
    }
```

it get the information out of the fields and my debugger stops at this point

```
 leraar.CreateTeacher(naam, voornaam, email, foto);
```

but it don't do the function and goes directly to this function

```
Response.Write("U hebt wat lege velden");
```

after doing

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Response.Write("U hebt wat lege velden. Exception = " + ex);
}
```

this is the outcome

```
U hebt wat lege velden, Exception = System.IndexOutOfRangeException: An SqlParameter with ParameterName '@achternaam' is not contained by this SqlParameterCollection. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection.GetParameter(String parameterName) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection.get_Item(String parameterName) at WFtyas.Leraren.CreateTeacher(String naam, String voornaam, String email, String foto) in C:\Users\Tyas\Dropbox\School\'15-'16\Bestanden\programmeren 2\WFtyas\WFtyas\App_Code\Leraren.cs:line 77 at WFtyas.intranet.leraren.Create.create() in C:\Users\Tyas\Dropbox\School\'15-'16\Bestanden\programmeren 2\WFtyas\WFtyas\intranet\leraren\Create.aspx.cs:line 32
```

ps: sorry for my bad english

Comment: use `Response.Write(ex.Tostring())` to see the exception details

Comment: Probably `leraar = new Leraren();` throws exception

Comment: how does your front-end aspx code look? And how is Leraren defined?

Comment: As @un-lucky said print the exception, also show us the constructor for teacher.

Comment: When there's an error that you're trying to correct, somehow *ignoring the error message* doesn't seem like a useful approach...

Comment: its fixed ... some wrong declared parameters for sql injection protection ... thanks for you're time guys !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An exception occurred in your function. You need to print the exception message in order to debug the error, as right now you are swallowing the exception message itself and losing all potentially useful information regarding it.

Change your catch block to the following in order to display the exception as part of your error message:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Response.Write("U hebt wat lege velden. Exception = " + ex);
}
```

Set breakpoints throughout your code and in your functions to debug and find exactly what is causing the exception to occur.

**Edit in response to updated question:**

From your exception message

> An SqlParameter with ParameterName '@achternaam' is not contained by this SqlParameterCollection

This indicates that you are doing an SQL query, and in the query you have specified `@achternaam`, but that you have not added it to the query as a parameter.